# How to create xml from html form in django

Tags: html, xml, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to create xml file from html form. I'm working with django and i want to insert html form data in my xml file.

I have the below fields in my html form:
a checkbox list
a textbox for inserting date from a calendar

```
<input type="file" file-accept="pdf, doc, docx, xls, csv, txt, rtf, html, zip, mp3, wma, mpg, flv, avi, jpg, jpeg, png, gif" file-maxsize="10240" />
```

Can you please guide me how i should do this? really thanx for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

top = Element('top')

comment = Comment('Generated for PyMOTW')
top.append(comment)

child = SubElement(top, 'child')
child.text = 'This child contains text.'

child_with_tail = SubElement(top, 'child_with_tail')
child_with_tail.text = 'This child has regular text.'
child_with_tail.tail = 'And "tail" text.'

child_with_entity_ref = SubElement(top, 'child_with_entity_ref')
child_with_entity_ref.text = 'This & that'

print tostring(top)
```

this is the way that you can create an xml file in python and put your html data wherever required

Apart from that you can use Django serialize  for xml also

Comment: thank you :)  
would you mind explaining it for me please? I want to know where i can put my html data in your code.